# Computational methods to find most cost storage & computationally efficient canonical form of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, computer-science, computational-mathematics

A matrix which has a factor of it's characteristic polynomial $\lambda^3 +1 = 0$ will be diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac 1 2 +i\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2} &0&0\\
0&-\frac 1 2 -i\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2} &0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$
Block-diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$ with two blocks (one $1\times 1$ block $\&$ and one $2\times 2$):

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
-\frac 1 2 &\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2} &0\\
-\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}&-\frac 1 2 &0\\ \hline
0&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$

And block diagonal over $\mathbb Z$ (one $3\times 3$ block):

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

But in general: is there some computational way to determine and quantify what / which would be most storage / computationally efficient in a computer?

---

**EDIT:** If we just consider the storage and computational constraints when calculating power series expansions for matrix functions:

$$f({\bf A}) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}{\bf A}^k = \sum_{k=0}^{N}{\bf SD}^k{\bf S}^{-1}$$

So that the ${\bf D}^k$ calculations applied on vectors are fast.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It depends on what you want to store. If you want to store a diagonalisation, you need to remember a basis somewhere. If you just want to store the data of "A diagonalisable $3 \times 3$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $x^3 + 1$", you could just store that data without ever expanding the matrix in memory.

Comment: Yes if we disregard what is required to store the basis vectors and focus on the computational gains for evaluating functions expanded as power series of matrices with the goal of the block having easy to store, fast and easy calculable powers.

Comment: "easy to store, fast and easy calculable" - this looks like one of those "choose two out of three" situations.

Comment: In this case I would guess the third one can often be implemented quite a bit faster than the other two in all three aspects on almost any architecture. Especially on primitive ones. Permutation completely removes need for multiplication or multiply-and-add. But I lack knowledge of any general theory of how to find such.